# Counting cells that match a value from value in another cell

Tags: excel, countif

I am really unfamiliar with Excel, but I stumbled upon a project where I am required to use it, so any kind of feedback would be much appreciated.

I have a csv file that has the filename, time and result, and it looks something like this.
[image]

On an external excel file I am required to calculate the average of the time(on column B) and the number of cells where the file name matches the result(data on column A without the ".jpg" and column C)

I currently have succeeded in calculating the average with the command below

=AVERAGE('file:///usr/local/elanpr-src/plateRecognitionResult.csv'#$plateRecognitionResult.B1:B100)

And I have tried calculating the number of cells that match with the following command, but seems to run into an error.

=COUNTIF(SUBSTITUTE('file:///usr/local/elanpr-src/plateRecognitionResult.csv'#$plateRecognitionResult.A1:A100, ".jpg", ""),'file:///usr/local/elanpr-src/plateRecognitionResult.csv'#$plateRecognitionResult.C1:C100)

It would be appreciated if anyone could tell me what I am doing wrong and what I can do to fix this.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Solved it via SUMPRODUCT

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(SUBSTITUTE('file:///usr/local/elanpr-src/plateRecognitionResult.csv'#$plateRecognitionResult.A1:A100,".jpg","")='file:///usr/local/elanpr-src
```